# Copy the entire bss and data segments of a C program from within the program?

Tags: c, memory, hpc

I'm trying to build a checkpoint-restart library for a specific HPC application. To perform a checkpoint, I need to be able to make copies of each processing element's global and static variables. I want to be able to do this by simply grabbing the contiguous block of memory where all of these variables -- initialized as well as uninitialized -- are stored and writing it to somewhere else.

I've Googled thoroughly and haven't come up with anything. I would be hugely grateful for any help. Any suggestions of better ways to solve this problem are more than welcome, too.

Comment: Multi-threaded, or single-threaded?  If multi-threaded, how will you ensure consistency while checkpointing?

Comment: Is there an operating system involved here?

Comment: *To perform a checkpoint, I need to be able to make copies of each processing element's global and static variables.*  You don't *need* to make a checkpoint that way, indeed I'd suggest it's an unusual way to make a checkpoint for an HPC application.  I'd suggest it is much more usual to write application code to save program state to disk to support a restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your compiler, these may be either in your heap or the data sections of the binary. I'm not familiar enough with the C standard to know exactly which aspects of the allocation process are guaranteed by the spec, but trying to dump these parts of memory and restore from them later on sounds like an approach with lots of hidden pitfalls. Not to mention the potential wasted time grabbing uninitialized memory.

I would recommend you instead explicitly dump what you need to an serial format like JSON, and restore from these binary files on restart. It will take more effort to set up and maintain this save and restore process, but I think it will be safer in the long run than dumping the entirety of your heap and data sections.

Comment: In my case it will take a lot more effort -- I'm trying to build this feature into a big, complicated application written by someone who is a few orders of magnitude more fluent in every aspect of CS than myself. I had hoped for a way to avoid going through and manually backing up each piece of state I need, but you're right: it's safer and wiser.